# Why do we allow referring to an enum member of an enum member in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Given the following enum:

```
enum Repeat {
    Daily,
    Weekly,
    Yearly
}
```

I realize we are able to write it this way:

```
Repeat repeat = Repeat.Daily.Weekly.Yearly.Weekly;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Repeat repeat = Repeat.Weekly;
```

May I know why such syntax is allowed? Is there a way to let the compiler warn us against this?

Comment: `Is there a way to let compiler warn us against this?` you should configure [Linter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692135/3872976) for that.

Comment: ["If the field is `static`: The *Primary* expression is evaluated, and the result is discarded. \[...\] The result \[of the field access expression\] is the value of the specified class variable in the class or interface that is the type of the *Primary* expression."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is allowed as `Daily, Weekly, Yearly` are the `static` field by `default` inside the `enum` and holds the object of `Repeat`.  Also, you will get a warning from the compiler `"The static field Repeat.Weekly should be accessed in a static way"`. It is similar to below lines of code.

```
class Foo{
    public static Foo obj1 = new Foo();
    public static Foo obj2 = new Foo();
    public static Foo obj3 = new Foo();
}

Foo f = Foo.obj1.obj2.obj3; // will work fine but you will get a warning from the compiler.
```

Here is some part of bytecode inspection of `Repeat` enum and from this, it is clear that `Enum` variable is `static` and holds the Object of Enum itself.

```
   0: new           #1                  // class com/java8/demo/Repeat
   3: dup
   4: ldc           #14                 // String Daily
   6: iconst_0
   7: invokespecial #15                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
  10: putstatic     #19                 // Field Daily:Lcom/java8/demo/Repeat;
  13: new           #1                  // class com/java8/demo/Repeat
```

Answer (score 5):

Enum instance are just `static` instance of the enum class.

We have two way to access static field of a class:

1. Via class itselft: Repeat.Daily
2. Via instance of class: Repeat.Daily.Daily

When you chain your enum:

```
Repeat repeat = Repeat.Daily.Weekly.Yearly.Weekly;
```

It's just like get a static field from an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to let compiler warn us against this?

Yes, **use a good IDE** and turn on warning. That way, you'll be notified as soon as your write the code, before you even compile it.

E.g. in [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/), it is called "Non-static access to static member":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enum literals are static members, and with each static member, one can access them either using the class reference:

```
TypeName.staticMember
TypeName.staticMethod()
```

Or on an instance:

```
new TypeName().staticMember
new TypeName().staticMethod()
```

The second approach is discouraged (and the compiler will issue a warning)

As enum literals are just static members, `Repeat.Daily.Weekly.Yearly.Weekly` is like the second code snippet above, accessing static members on instance references.

With a class, that would be:

```
class Type {
    static Type INSTANCE1, INSTANCE2, INSTANCE3;
}
```

And one can get a reference to `INSTANCE3` using `Type.INSTANCE1.INSTANCE2.INSTANCE3`. It's valid, but it's bad practice.