# gitlab CI pipeline to check for code formatting

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, githooks, pre-commit-hook, linter

I am looking to install `google-java-formatter` across several of my projects.

However when committing code I want the `CI` pipline to check if the formatting has been done first.

I know I can accomplish this with a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in my root directory however I am very unsure how to achieve my goal of checking if all files have been formatted correctly, can anyone help me out with how you could do this with `google-java-formatter` and `gitlab` please.

Comment: You can also use the [spotless plugin](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless) if you use SBT, Maven or Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

## `google-java-formatter` for code formatting

Since `google-java-formatter` brings modifications (formatting) to the code, then it changes the code to be commited.

As per [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) source code:

> `google-java-format` is a program that reformats Java source code to comply with [Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

So, you need a `pre-commit` hook.

E.g. you can use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) - A framework for managing and maintaining multi-language pre-commit hooks.

Sample file you can see [here](https://github.com/leytono/pre_commit_hooks/blob/master/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml)

.pre-commit-hooks.yaml:

```
- id: eclipse-formatter
  name: Eclipse Java Formatter
  description: This hook formats Java code with the Eclipse formatter.
  entry: eclipse-formatter
  language: python
  types:
    - java
- id: google-java-formatter
  name: Google Java Formatter
  description: This hook formats Java code with Google Java Formatter.
  entry: google-java-formatter
  language: python
  types:
    - java
```

If you do want to integrate git hooks with `GitLab`, try to create custom [GitLab Server hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/server_hooks.html)

## linters vs formatters

As you said:

> when committing code I want the CI pipeline to check if the formatting has been done first.

What are you asking - is `checkstyle linting` not `formatting`
So, to check if formatting is already done, you can use some linter.

I.e. [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691926/is-there-a-simple-cli-java-linter):

- [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) (earlier [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)) for finding existing bugs. VERY GOOD!
- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) for finding patterns that can lead to bugs (e.g. unused variables)
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to enforce coding standards and conventions (e.g. whitespace, Javadoc)
- [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/) hooks right into your application's compile step

### `checkstyle` linter usage

There are many guides on that, e.g: [GitLab CI/CD Pipeline for Maven-Based Applications – The Blog of Ivan Krizsan](https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2019/09/28/gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-for-maven-based-applications/)

Also, there are [250+ samples of `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://github.com/search?q=checkstyle+filename%3A.gitlab-ci.yml+language%3AYAML+language%3AYAML&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=YAML&l=YAML) with `checkstyle.

```yaml
Client_Checkstyle:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
    - cat checkstyle-result.xml
  allow_failure: false
```

Comment: Im still a bit unsure how to use this in gitlab, I add this file to my root directory and then will the pipeline pick up on this file? I am using inteliJ if that makes any difference to the answer

Comment: Added some links and ready example piece of `.gitlab-ci.yml`, pls check

Comment: @Yasen Is Gitlab necessary for this?